# printf produces extra % when printing to stdout

Tags: c, printing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int year = 2017;
    int month = 8;
    int date = 8;

    printf("%i/%i/%i", date, month, year);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is my code. I would like it to print

> 8/8/2017

but it actually prints

> 8/8/2017%

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using `zsh`? Some shells print a `%` when your program prints output without a trailing newline. The `%` is a standin delimiter to separate program output from the next shell prompt. Look at [Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol)

Add a newline character to the end of your print statement to get rid of it:

```
printf("%i/%i/%i\n",date , month , year);
```

---

I have `zsh` on my Macintosh, and I can reproduce this behaviour. Here's a simple `C` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world!");

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://puu.sh/x4CHL/54ba653c5b.png):

```
$ ./a.out
Hello world!%
```

Comment: Hardly standard, bur rather non-standard behavior. I've never heard of this before. This seems to be some quirk of one particular *nix flavour.

Comment: @Lundin The choice of shell, rather than the OS, I believe is the culprit. I have zsh on my mac, and it does the exact same thing... that's why I know, or at least can claim to know what OP's problem is.